# Why is a mold required in isostatic pressing after performing Sintering

Tags: post-processing, laser, metal-printing, metal-parts, printing-powder

After an a object is formed through direct laser sintering, as a post-processing procedure the object is sent for hot-isostatic pressing, In hot isostatic pressing the sintered object is placed in a mold and then pressure and heat are applied.
I was wondering what would go wrong if the bare object without the mold was made to undergo pressing? Remember the sintered object already has a shape acquired during sintering so it may need a mold to get a specific shape during pressing. My assumption- In hot isostatic pressing the object might get softened and hence deformed due to heat and thus the requirement of a mold to keep the object firm. Is this assumption true??
And apart from deformation are there any other undesirable effects caused to the un-molded object during hot isostatic pressing?

Comment: It isn't done in a mold, not at the company I work. Very high pressure and temperature of an inert gas in a pressure vessel. We print in Aluminum-, Titanium- and Nickel based Superalloys. Note that it isn't that porous to change the dimensions drastically.

Comment: @0scar Is there any specific name given to the process